# Problem with show dynamic values depend on language

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I working on some private project and like to have multilanguage UI.

I translated all languages of static text, which works nicely. But have issues when need to show translated text from backend API. I get for example `place.about.en` and `place.about.es` (where es or en is the name of language) and didn't know how to show each and if for example if `ES` didn't exists show `EN` value. Does anybody have some idea how to handle it?

Comment: are you using ngx-translate? if you share some sample code then it will be easier to answer, but you can use ngx-translate package for both static and dynamic translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone also has the same issue. You can use this package ngx-translate and [this tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-multi-language-translation-feature-in-ionic-application-using-ngx-translate/#.X36IIpMzZTY) to make a multilanguage Ionic application. Then if you need something like I do, you simply add into the language file
`"PLACE_INFO": {"about": "{{about.en}}"}` and into ionic page this one `<p class="ion-text-wrap">{{'PLACE_INFO.about' | translate:placeInfo}}</p>` and Ionic will bind your API response text into your view and show it in correct way.